# Sharing large sqlalchemy objects between flask templates

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, large-data

I have a flask application, which I want to use to do some data visualization of a very large dataset that I have in a postgresql database.

I have sqlalchemy, plotly, google maps set up, but my current problem is that I want to fetch a rather large dataset from my database and pass that to a template that will take care of doing some different visualizations. I only want to load the data in once, when the site is started, and then avoid running it later on when navigating the other pages.

## which methods can I use to achieve this? And how can I access the data that I get in other pages (templates)?

I read somewhere about `session` and I tried to implement such a functionality, but then I got a "not serializable error", which I fixed by parsing my object to JSON, but then I got a "too large header" error. I feel like I'm sort of out of possiblities..

Just to show some code, here is what I'm currently messing around with.

#### Models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, JSON, Text
from app import db

class Table910(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_910'

    id = db.Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    did = db.Column(Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)
    data = db.Column(JSON)
    db_timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)

    def items(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'did': self.did, 'timestamp': self.timestamp, 'data': self.data, 'db_timestamp': self.db_timestamp}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<1_Data %r, %r>' % (self.did, self.id)
```

#### Views.py

```
from flask import render_template, session
from app import app, db, models
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json
import plotly

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    # fetching from the database (takes ~50 seconds to run)
    rows = models.Table910.query \
        .filter_by(did='357139052424715') \
        .filter((models.Table910.timestamp > 1466846920000) & (models.Table910.timestamp < 1467017760000)) \
        .order_by(models.Table910.timestamp.asc())

    # 
    # managing and drawing data on plots
    #

    return render_template('index.html', 
                           ids=ids, 
                           graphJSON=graphJSON, 
                           rows=rows, 
                           routeCoordinates=routeCoordinates))
```

## EDIT:

I might have explained my problem a little too vaguely, therefore to elaborate a little I want to use a specific page to load the data, and then have another page take care of drawing the graphs. The best procedure I can think of currently would be to be able to press a button to get the data and once data is loaded press another button to draw the graphs.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The data stored in a `session` is placed in a signed cooky. The maximum size for a cooky is around 4096 bytes. You should not store big data in there.

Comment: Ahh I see. Good to know. Well then that is not the procedure I should use. I feel like using a file to write to, as long as no one has a better suggestion.